# Which plugin / hotkey opened this help window?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am using Vim to write a script in Python.

In `~/.vim/plugin` I have these:

- `acp.vim`
- `cscope_maps.vim`
- `l9.vim`

In `~/.vim/autoload` I have these:

- `acp.vim`
- `l9/`
- `l9.vim`
- `pathogen.vim`

When I am in the Vim editor, I don't know which key I pressed, and then a popup in the top of the editor shows information about function and parameters with explanation (the same as `help(python)` in the Python interpreter).

I don't know which shortcut opened that help, and what is shortcut to enable/disable it in the Vim editor. (Or what plugin was involved.)

[free movies torrent - http://torrent4all.com](http://torrent4all.com)

[image: screen shot here]

Comment: My advice: don't use Vim.

Comment: What you're looking at there is called the preview window.  I don't know what opened it but you can close it with `:pclose` or just `:pc`.

Comment: `:help preview-window` will take you to the help, which includes a number of hotkeys that might have opened a preview window.

Comment: @romainl I think should use what you like :D

Thanks Randy Morris, Dan Lowe

Comment: One should work with a tool he knows.

Comment: Probably on pressing 'K' (Capital K). It is used to view documentation.